# How to make a page accessible even user is not logged in

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-blade

I have a page which is a company page in which should be accessible even the user is not logged in. I am using blade template in which is called in all other pages. My problem now is I'm having an issue with this one:

```
<div class="profimg fitimg">
     <img src="{{ Auth::user()->photo == null ? url('assets/images/profile.png') : Auth::user()->photo }}" alt="">
</div>
```

It will return an error

> Trying to get property 'photo' of non-object (View: /var/www/resources/views/layouts/user/mypage.blade.php)

This part of my template gets the users profile photo. In my web.php, it looks like this:

```
Route::prefix('/')->group(function() {
    Route::get('company', function () {
        return view('user.company');
    });
});
```

And I also have this if the user is logged in.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:user'], function () {
    //routes for auth user
});
```

My problem now is, how can I make a page accessible by public even though they are not logged in? And if they are logged in, I can get their profile info in my template. I think there's some sort of solution for this one but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to pass the data instead of directly accessing a class. So, if you change the route to this -

```
Route::prefix('/')->group(function() {
    Route::get('company', function () {
        $data['user'] = Auth::user();
        return view('user.company', $data);
    });
});
```

The user item of data array should have some value if the user is logged in. Then you can check if user has any data and change your html like this-

```
<div class="profimg fitimg">
    @if($user)
        <img src="{{ $user->photo }}" alt="{{ $user->name }}">
    @else
        <img src="{{ url('assets/images/profile.png') }}" alt="default profile image">
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this one but accessing `Auth::user()` inside the web.php will not give any data.

Comment: Auth::user() facade should return logged users data or NULL if not logged in. You are checking exactly that in your view file. If the $user has any data, show logged users image, otherwise show a default image.

Comment: Yes I understand. But you can't access `Auth::user()` in web.php file.

Comment: You can access "Auth Facade" in web.php. Are you getting any exception? Try using "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;" right after php tag in web.php. Check [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/facades#when-to-use-facades) for more details about facades. You can also check and use [Authentication Directives](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#control-structures) in your blade file if you are still facing any issues.

Comment: Tried adding it, but still no data retrieved.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, inside of laravel blade, you don't need to put php tags. You should use double curly brackets instead.

If you want to completely hide the image when a user is not logged in, you can try this:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    <img src=" {{ Auth::user()->photo ?? url('assets/images/profile.png') }} ">
@endif
```

If you want to show the placeholder when the user is not logged in, or if no image has been set, try this:

```
@if(Auth::check() && !empty(Auth::user()->photo))
   <img src=" {{ Auth::user()->photo }} ">
@else
   <img src="{{ url('assets/images/profile.png') }}"
@endif
```

Comment: I have updated my question regarding your concern for I have copied the error output than my original code. And my concern is not answered in your answer :) Thanks anyway. I think I have to make a separate template for authenticated and non-authenticated users.

Comment: You should always avoid having two templates that are very similar, you can run into problems with updating one and forgetting to update the other. What is it that still isn't working?